# Можно ли так передавать context и не приведет ли это к утечке памяти?

Tags: android, java

```
public class A{  
public static void fileRead(Context context){  
FileOutputStream fos=context.openFileOutput("file", context.MODE_PRIVATE);  
...  
}   
}

public class B extends Activity{  
@Override  
protected void onCreate(){   
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
A.fileRead(this);

}  
}
```

Comment: Это легко проверить. Берёте зaмеряете память до и после использования, предварительно вызвав GC. Пару раз прокрутите - всё станет ясно.

Answer (score 1):

Не приведёт. Потому что после чтения счётчик объектов, которые ссылаются на этот контекст уменьшиться при очистке Garbage Collector'ом.