# Как создать объект для работы с базой данных не передавая в конструктор Contex?

Tags: android

Создаю объект для работы с БД в отдельном потоке, т.е. вне активити.
Где мне брать `Context`?

Я нашел два подобных вопроса здесь, но достоверного ответа КАК это сделать, к сожалению, нет.

[Как лучше всего хранить Context?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/125428/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-context)

[Можно ли так передавать context и не приведет ли это к утечке памяти?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/296382/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-context-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8)

Comment: Добавте Context в конструктор вашего потока - Унаследуйтесь от Thread, и добавьте Context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Можно передать ссылку на `Context` в аргумент метода, вызывающего БД.
2. Можно получать ссылку на `Context` из статического метода переопределённого класса Application. Это называется синглтон, делается так:

   ```
   public final class MySingleton extends Application {
      private Context ctx;

     @Override
     public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //инициализация объектов синглетона
        this.ctx=this;
     }

     public static Context getContext() {
       //по идее можно и просто this возвращать.
       return this.ctx;
     } 
   }
   ```

Получать `Context` теперь можно так:

```
 MySingleton.getContext():
```

И надо добавить в манифест, что приложение имеет переопределённый класс `Application`:

```
<application android:name=".MySingleton"
```

Тут подробнее: [тык](http://derevyanko.blogspot.ru/2010/12/android_26.html)

**P.S.** Синглтон, вроде как, антипаттерн, так что лучше пользовать первый вариант.

Comment: ```P.S. Синглтон, вроде как, антипаттерн, так что лучше пользовать первый вариант.``` можете обяснить проблему. Чем чревато использование Синглтон?

Comment: @Tany, вот немного об этом на англо-саксонском: [тык](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12755616/3212712)